# gluonfx:run results in "module javafx.graphics does not "opens javafx.scene" to unnamed module"

Tags: java, javafx, gluon, gluonfx

I am in the process of upgrading an old (JDK 8) JavaFX application to JDK 17 plus all of its dependencies. So far the process went okay, but now I am stuck on something that I can't seem to figure out. If I run the JavaFX application without the gluonFX plugin, it seems to work. However, I want to package it and distribute it to other parties, which is why I am using the gluonfx-maven-plugin. However, trying to run **gluonfx-run** results in the following stack trace:

```
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make protected javafx.collections.ObservableList javafx.scene.Parent.getChildren() accessible: module javafx.graphics does not "opens javafx.scene" to unnamed module @7ac9b2c5
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:354)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:297)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.checkCanSetAccessible(Method.java:199)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.setAccessible(Method.java:193)
    at org.jacpfx.rcp.util.FXUtil.getChildren(FXUtil.java:99)
    at org.jacpfx.rcp.util.WorkerUtil.handleAdd(WorkerUtil.java:130)
    at org.jacpfx.rcp.util.WorkerUtil.addComponentByType(WorkerUtil.java:117)
    at org.jacpfx.rcp.worker.FXComponentInitWorker.lambda$executePostHandleAndAddComponent$119(FXComponentInitWorker.java:222)
    at org.jacpfx.rcp.util.WorkerUtil.lambda$invokeOnFXThreadAndWait$34(WorkerUtil.java:79)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:457)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:456)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
```

So far I have tried to add the following JVM arguments:

```
--module-path /Users/macuser/.sdkman/candidates/javafx/javafx-sdk-17.0.9/lib --add-modules javafx.base,javafx.controls,javafx.fxml,javafx.graphics --add-opens javafx.graphics/javafx.scene=ALL-UNNAMED
```

This does not seem to work. Still gives me the same issue. I'm not sure if the module-path is necessary, as I am using Maven to include these dependencies.

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
      <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
      <version>${openjfx.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
      <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
      <version>${openjfx.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
      <artifactId>javafx-swing</artifactId>
      <version>${openjfx.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
      <artifactId>javafx-web</artifactId>
      <version>${openjfx.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

I really want to make this work with GraalVM to run the application natively. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: You are using an outdated third party dependency (`JacpFX`) which tries to do some [reflection operation](https://github.com/JacpFX/JacpFX/blob/master/JACP.JavaFX/src/main/java/org/jacpfx/rcp/util/FXUtil.java#L98) that worked a while ago, but it is not permitted anymore. In any case, you can enabled it adding `--add-opens javafx.graphics/javafx.scene=ALL-UNNAMED` to the JavaFX Maven plugin configuration `<options/>` (which is then used by the GluonFX plugin). (Make sure `mvn javafx:run` in the first place)

Comment: @JoséPereda thanks for replying. I tried adding --add-opens javafx.graphics/javafx.scene=ALL-UNNAMED to the VM options in my IntelliJ run configuration and it did not work.

Comment: Did you try `<options><option>--add-opens<option/><option>javafx.graphics/javafx.scene=ALL-UNNAMED<option/><options/>` as part of the JavaFX Maven plugin configuration?

Comment: Hello @JoséPereda, sorry for replying this late. First of all, happy new year to you! The holidays approached and was out of the country and I didn't bring my work laptop. I just tried to add the 2 options to the plugin, and this seems to work. I'm not getting any stacktrace now. Thank you!!!